# How can I render a <template /> tag with react?

Tags: reactjs, web-component, jsx, documentfragment

Sometimes you might need to render web-components from your react app.

Web-components often use a special `<template> ... </template>` tag.
But if I try to render such markup with react like this:

```jsx
render() {
  return (
    <template>
      <div>some content</div>
    </template>
  )
}
```

then my web-components don't work correctly.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The reason is that JSX does a different job than what the `<template />` tags exists for. The idea of a template tag is to *not render its children* and pretty much handle it like unparsed text (the browser actually parses it just to make sure its valid html, but does nothing more)

But when you write this in JSX:

```jsx
return (
  <template>
    <div>some content</div>
  </template>
)
```

you're basically instructing react to create a `'template'` element and then **create a `'div'` element** and then to append this `div` to the `template` as a child.

So under hood this happens:

```js
const template = document.createElement('template')
const div = document.createElement('div')
const text = document.createTextNode('some text')
div.appendChild(text)
template.appendChild(div)
```

But what you want is to set the contents of the `<template />` as a string. You can use `innerHTML` for that.

---

### Solution

One solution would be:

```jsx
render() {
  return (
    <template
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
        __html: '<div>some content</div>'
      }}
    />
  )
}
```

Now you're asking react to create all those children tags as node elements but letting the browser decide what to do with them.

#### Nicer solution

You might not want to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` all the time. So let's create a helper component:

```jsx
function Template({ children, ...attrs }) {
  return (
    <template
      {...attrs}
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: children }}
    />
  );
}
```

Now any time you need to use a template you can use it like this:

```jsx
render() {
  return (
    <Template>
      {'<div>some content</div>'}
    </Template>
  )
}
```

Don't forget to put the inner content in quotes, because it should be a string.

Comment: dangerouslySetInnerHTML won't work if the template contains scripts (which happens to be my use case).

Comment: I'm having the same issue! @Christophe were you find any solution?

Comment: I think I gave up, but the most promising path was Range.createContextualFragment() which does let the scripts run. Probably used with a Reactjs ref.

Comment: I solved it by wrapping the children in `ReactDomServer.renderToString`

Answer (score 0):

I know that this question has already an answer, but there is another, I guess simpler solution to do that creating hoc (Higher Order Component).

Just create new "component" like this:

```
// hoc/Template.js
const template = props => props.children
export default template
```

and then you can use it in your project this way:

```
import './hoc/Template.js'

...

render() {
  return (
    <Template>
      {'<div>some content</div>'}
    </Template>
  )
}
```

Newer version of react has already build it such a component, so you can achieve same thing without creating component.

```
import { Fragment } from 'react'

...

render() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      {'<div>some content</div>'}
    </Fragment>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a bug in React! https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/19932

When the native browser parses the `<template>` tag, it appends all children to the template's `content` fragment, instead of adding them as `children`.  So a template should never actually have any `children`.

However, if you programmatically build the DOM (the way `react-dom` does), then the template will have an **empty** `content` fragment, since all children are added as children.  This is why web components will not behave properly with these templates.

Here's an example of the problem too: https://codesandbox.io/s/new-sun-8l62o?file=/src/App.tsx:1056-1118

The easiest workaround is to use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`, like so:

```
<template dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: `
  <p> Some text </p>
` }} />
```

This is limited by the fact that you can only supply raw HTML (no custom React elements).  However, since you're using the `<template>` tag in the first place, it seems highly unlikely that you'd also be using React within the template.